# $scope variable value is not changing in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have passed a scope variable to a function where i am trying to change it even though the value is being accessible inside the function its values doesnt change.

Here is my html

```
<div class="console_item" ng-class="dropdwns.assetshow==true?'showdrp':'hidedrp'" ng-click="drpdwn(dropdwns.assetshow)">Asset Type</div>
```

Here is the code in my controller

```
$scope.dropdwns={assetshow:false};
$scope.drpdwn=function(dat){
    if(dat==true)
    {
        dat=false;
    }
    else
    {
        dat=true;
    }
    console.log($scope.dropdwns);
}
```

I tried $apply but it gives me an error.Can someone help me thank you.

Comment: `dat` is a local variable. It's not a pointer. Changing it won't change the original parameter.

Comment: So i have to write seperate function for each object?

Comment: No. If flipping the boolean is really the only thing you want to do, it's easiest to drop the function and just do `dropdwns.assetshow=!dropdwns.assetshow` in the view.

Comment: Why U change the "dat", why not just do: $scope.dropdwns.asstshow=!$scope.dropdwns.asstshow inside the function?     you can do in your HTML:  ng-click="dropdwns.asstshow=!dropdwns.asstshow" and it also will work

Comment: If it's more complex than the boolean flip then you'd do `dropdwns.assetshow=drpdwn(dropdwns.assetshow)` and return the new value from the function.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set to the correct variable

```
$scope.dropdwns={assetshow:false};
$scope.drpdwn=function(dat){
    $scope.dropdwns.assetshow = !dat; // Here
    console.log($scope.dropdwns);
};
```

Comment: dropdwns is a list of objects like assetshow.I cant equate assetshow=!dat

Comment: Moreover this is a small example i made not the original code so it isnt just true/false

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the object to the function, not its property:

```
    <div class="console_item" ng-class="dropdwns.assetshow==true?'showdrp':'hidedrp'" ng-click="drpdwn(dropdwns)">Asset Type</div>

    $scope.drpdwn=function(dat){
    if(dat.assetshow == true)
    {
        dat.assetshow = false;
    }
    else
    {
        dat.assetshow = true;
    }

    //A more simple version dat.assetshow = !dat.assetshow
    console.log($scope.dropdwns);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer:

```
 <div class="console_item" ng-class="{'showdrp':dropdwns.assetshow, 'hidedrp':!dropdwns.assetshow}" ng-click="dropdwns.assetshow = !dropdwns.assetshow">Asset Type</div>
```